# Azure Media Service : Retry failed after 6 tries. (The operation was canceled.)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-media-services

To learn about Azure Media Service I'm following [Tutorial: Upload, encode, and stream videos with Media Services v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-api).
But currently stuck as code given in this article [UploadEncodeAndStreamFiles](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-tutorials/tree/master/AMSV3Tutorials/UploadEncodeAndStreamFiles) is throwing `Retry failed after 6 tries. (The operation was canceled.)` exception during file upload at `await blob.UploadAsync(fileToUpload);`.

```
private static async Task<Asset> CreateInputAssetAsync(
        IAzureMediaServicesClient client,
        string resourceGroupName,
        string accountName,
        string assetName,
        string fileToUpload)
    {
        // In this example, we are assuming that the asset name is unique.
        //
        // If you already have an asset with the desired name, use the Assets.Get method
        // to get the existing asset. In Media Services v3, the Get method on entities returns null 
        // if the entity doesn't exist (a case-insensitive check on the name).

        // Call Media Services API to create an Asset.
        // This method creates a container in storage for the Asset.
        // The files (blobs) associated with the asset will be stored in this container.
        Asset asset = await client.Assets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, assetName, new Asset());

        // Use Media Services API to get back a response that contains
        // SAS URL for the Asset container into which to upload blobs.
        // That is where you would specify read-write permissions 
        // and the exparation time for the SAS URL.
        var response = await client.Assets.ListContainerSasAsync(
            resourceGroupName,
            accountName,
            assetName,
            permissions: AssetContainerPermission.ReadWrite,
            expiryTime: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(4).ToUniversalTime());

        var sasUri = new Uri(response.AssetContainerSasUrls.First());

        // Use Storage API to get a reference to the Asset container
        // that was created by calling Asset's CreateOrUpdate method.  
        BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(sasUri);
        BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient(Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload));

        // Use Strorage API to upload the file into the container in storage.
        await blob.UploadAsync(fileToUpload);

        return asset;
    }
```

Following is the detailed exception & exception trace:

```
Count = 6
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2146233088
HelpLink: null
InnerException: {"The operation was canceled."}
InnerExceptions: Count = 6
Message: "Retry failed after 6 tries. (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.) (The operation was canceled.)"
Source: "Azure.Core"
StackTrace: "   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.<ProcessAsync>d__11.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.<ProcessAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.<ProcessAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.<ProcessAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAnd
```

DebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.BlockBlob.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient.d__26.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.<<GetPartitionedUploaderBehaviors>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Thro w()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Azure.Storage.PartitionedUploader`2.<UploadInternal>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.d__29.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.<UploadAsync>d__28.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionSe rvices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.d__20.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.<UploadAsync>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.d__12.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Run
time.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at UploadEncodeAndStreamFiles.Program.<CreateInputAssetAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\\Study\\Test Source Code\\Video Portal\\media-services-v3-dotnet-tutorials-master\\AMSV3Tutorials\\UploadEncodeAndStreamFiles\\Program.cs:line 210\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at UploadEncodeAndStreamFiles.Program.d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Study\Test Source Code\Video Portal\media-services-v3-dotnet-tutorials-master\AMSV3Tutorials\UploadEncodeAndStreamFiles\Program.cs:line 82\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.Comp
ilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at UploadEncodeAndStreamFiles.Program.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Study\Test Source Code\Video Portal\media-services-v3-dotnet-tutorials-master\AMSV3Tutorials\UploadEncodeAndStreamFiles\Program.cs:line 34"
TargetSite: {Void MoveNext()}

```
{"The operation was canceled."}
CancellationToken: IsCancellationRequested = true
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2146233029
HelpLink: null
InnerException: {"Error while copying content to a stream."}
Message: "The operation was canceled."
Source: "System.Net.Http"
StackTrace: "   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsyncCore>d__53.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync>d__48.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithRetryAsync>d__47.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.Exce
```

ptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__71.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwa
iter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.d__7.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.d__10.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.d__9.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.Compiler
Services.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.d__8.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaite
r.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.LoggingPolicy.d__7.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.d__11.MoveNext()"
TargetSite: {Void MoveNext()}
Task: null

```
{"Error while copying content to a stream."}
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2146232800
HelpLink: null
InnerException: {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.."}
Message: "Error while copying content to a stream."
Source: "System.Net.Http"
StackTrace: "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<CopyToAsyncCore>d__49.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendRequestContentAsync>d__58.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsyncCore>d__53.MoveNext()"
TargetSite: {Void MoveNext()}


{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.."}
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HResult: -2146232800
HelpLink: null
InnerException: {"The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."}
Message: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.."
Source: "System.Net.Sockets"
StackTrace: "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<<WriteSingleChunk>g__CompleteAsync|210_1>d`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<WriteAsyncChunked>d__209`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<WriteAsyncInternal>d__216`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.
```

HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__66.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.IO.Stream.d__30.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.RequestContent.StreamContent.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.PipelineRequest.PipelineContentAdapter.<
SerializeToStreamAsync>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.d__49.MoveNext()"
TargetSite: {Void ThrowException(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError, System.Threading.CancellationToken)}

```
{"The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."}
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
ErrorCode: 995
HResult: -2147467259
HelpLink: null
InnerException: null
Message: "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."
NativeErrorCode: 995
SocketErrorCode: OperationAborted
Source: null
StackTrace: null
TargetSite: null
```

Have anyone else faced such issue? If Yes, can you please help what might be causing this issue? Am I missing an permission causing this issue?

Answer (score 6):

This seem to happen when you are on a low bandwidth upload network. You can add

```
BlobUploadOptions upOptions = new BlobUploadOptions
        {
            TransferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
            {
                MaximumTransferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024,
                InitialTransferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024
            }
        };
        // Use Strorage API to upload the file into the container in storage.
        await blob.UploadAsync(file,upOptions);
```

that will change the chunk size and make it work with the lower bandwidth.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Jason's answer, just a couple of modifications.

First I would remove the endless while loop.
Second, referencing the github issue thread, I think the most important point out that the `BlobClientOptions` should be passed when constructing either the `BlobContainerClient` or `BlobClient`. Then specify Transport.
As mentioned here in the thread
[Tweaking Transport in BlobClientOptions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/9212#issuecomment-575310337)

```
new BlobClientOptions
{
    Transport = new HttpClientTransport(
        new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(102) })
};
```

I saw that the above in Jason's comment he left this commented out, but this would be an integral part solving the problem.

You can also look to extending the retry period this request requires more than 6 tries to make a successful connection.

```
new BlobClientOptions // or whatever options class suitable for your client
{
    Transport = new HttpClientTransport( new HttpClient { Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan } ),
    Retry = { NetworkTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2022

I was trying to run a `TimerTriggered` Azure function locally, and I was facing this problem. After hours of troubleshooting I found out that I had the flag
`UseDevelopmentStorage=true` but the `AzureStorageEmulator` tool was not running.

Once I started the emulator the error was gone & the function was working as expected.

Comment: where do you set this flag?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error: "Retry failed after 6 tries"

Cause for me was CORS issue.
Go to AzureStorage..
find CORS in the settings

Add comma seperated values for your LocalHost, and WebURL to access the storage.

Add * for AllowedHeaders

Add * for ExposedHeeaders

Add MaxAge = 5

Checkmark all your Methods you want.. (GET, POST, etc...)

[image]

This got rid of the "Retry failed after 6 tries error" for me, and i was able to upload my blobs.  I was using BlazorWASM but really should be same for all other project types on web.