# Display upload progress to Azure BLOB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

The following code demonstrates a file upload to Azure BLOB. I will be uploading larger files therefore, there's a risk of me getting a failure in uploading due to low bandwidth issue (Discussed in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935824/azure-media-service-retry-failed-after-6-tries-the-operation-was-canceled)).

The following code works fine, but I need a way to show the upload progress to the end user in the form of a Percentage %. How can I amend my code to make it possible ?

```
BlobUploadOptions op = new BlobUploadOptions
{
    TransferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
    {
        MaximumTransferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024,
        InitialTransferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024,
        MaximumConcurrency= 5
     },
     HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders
     {
        ContentType = request.Request.ContentType
     }
};

Azure.Response<BlobContentInfo> ci = await 
   blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, op);
```

Comment: You have to use `BlobUploadOpions.ProgressHandler` to listen to upload progress events and then stream this to the frontend in real time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try something like the following:

```
//Define a progress handler.
class MyProgressHandler : IProgress<long>
{
    public void Report(long value)
    {
        //Do something to report the progress. I am simply printing the bytes uploaded.
        Console.WriteLine($"Bytes uploaded: {value}");
    }
}

//Use the progress handler in your upload options.
BlobUploadOptions op = new BlobUploadOptions
{
    TransferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
    {
        MaximumTransferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024,
        InitialTransferSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024,
        MaximumConcurrency= 5
     },
     HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders
     {
        ContentType = request.Request.ContentType
     },
     ProgressHandler = new MyProgressHandler()
};
```

Comment: Just a followup question, how do you send the value of the bytes uploaded into the front-end

Comment: I have no clue, sorry. However if I were doing this upload, I would have opted for direct upload to Azure Storage from browser using Shared Access Signature instead of doing the upload from this web tier.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a newbie. What are the advantages of doing so

Comment: The biggest advantage is that you're reducing the load on your web server as upload requests are not coming to your web server first and then going to your storage. Secondly since you're bypassing the web server and directly uploading from browser to storage (which you anyways want to do), it is much faster.

Comment: My requirement is that I need to upload a file which is of size 500mb - 1Gb. In that case according to you the browser will be able to directly upload to Azure Blob without going through the Web layer. Am I correct ?

Comment: That is correct. You will need to use Azure Storage SDK for JavaScript. Essentially the JavaScript SDK will do the same thing as your .Net SDK is doing it currently. 2 things though: 1) You will need to configure CORS rules on the Storage account properly so that cross-domain AJAX requests are allowed and 2) You will need to use Shared Access Signature (storage account key will not work in JavaScript). For #2, you could have an endpoint in the API that would create a SAS URL and return it back to the browser. JavaScript SDK would use this SAS URL for uploading.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri --I ended up going with your approach in the comments here and it's blazingly fast by comparison!

@Illep if you do choose to go the SAS route, the BlockBlobUploadOptions interface offers an `onProgress` property which allows you to easily report progress on the frontend.